# Java Streams - group-by and return a Nested Map

Tags: java, group-by, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

my data is like this,

```
unitId  time  value1 value2
 a      2021    10    11   
 a      2022    15    13
 b      2021    20    25
 b      2022    30    37
```

my goal is put every unitId and value into a map like this,

```
{
  'a': {'2021_value1': 10, '2021_value2': 11, '2022_value1': 15, '2022_value2': 13},
  'b': {'2021_value1': 20, '2021_value2': 25, '2022_value1': 30, '2022_value2': 37},
}
```

I already figure out two ways to achieve that, here is my code,

```
public class Unit {

    public String unitId;

    public Integer year;

    public Integer value1;

    public Integer value2;

    public static Unit of(String unitId, Integer year, Integer value1, Integer value2) {
        Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.unitId = unitId;
        unit.year = year;
        unit.value1 = value1;
        unit.value2 = value2;
        return unit;
    }

}
```

and,

```
public class UnitTest {

    private static void printMap(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map) {
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            String vStr = v.entrySet().stream().map(a -> String.format("%s: %s", a.getKey(), a.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
            System.out.printf("%s: {%s}%n", k, vStr);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Unit> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(Unit.of("a", 2021, 10,  11 ));
        list.add(Unit.of("a", 2022, 15,  13));
        list.add(Unit.of("b", 2021, 20,  25));
        list.add(Unit.of("b", 2022, 30,  37));

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map1 = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                x -> x.unitId,
                Collector.of(
                    HashMap::new,
                    (x, y) -> {
                        x.put(String.format("%s_%s", y.year, "value1"), y.value1);
                        x.put(String.format("%s_%s", y.year, "value2"), y.value2);
                    },
                    (x, y) -> {x.putAll(y); return x;}
                )
            )
        );

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map2 = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                x -> x.unitId,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    x -> x.stream()
                        .flatMap(y -> Stream.of(
                                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(String.format("%s_%s", y.year, "value1"), y.value1),
                                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(String.format("%s_%s", y.year, "value2"), y.value2)
                             ))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                     AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, 
                                     AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)))
            )
        );
        printMap(map1);
        printMap(map2);
    }
}
```

First one more like write the processing manually, second one uses temporary lists which may not be necessary. Is there any direct or simple way to do this, like use *Collectors.toMap* API or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any direct or simple way to do this, like use Collectors.toMap API or something else?

If you want to utilize only *built-in collectors*, you might try a combination of `groupingBy()` and [`teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)).

`Collectors.teeing()` expects three *arguments*: `2` downstream *collectors* and a `merger` *function*. Each element from the stream will be passed into both *collectors*, and when these collectors are done, results produced by them will get merged by the *function*.

In the code below, `toMap()` is used as both *downstream collectors* of `teeing()`. And each of these *collectors* is responsible for retrieving its type of *value*.

The code might look like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Unit> list =
        List.of(Unit.of("a", 2021, 10,  11 ),
                Unit.of("a", 2022, 15,  13),
                Unit.of("b", 2021, 20,  25),
                Unit.of("b", 2022, 30,  37));

    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Unit::getUnitId,
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    unit -> unit.getYear() + "_value1",
                    Unit::getValue1),
            Collectors.toMap(
                    unit -> unit.getYear() + "_value2",
                    Unit::getValue2),
                (values1, values2) -> {values1.putAll(values2); return values1;})
        ));

    printMap(map);
}
```

*Output:*

```
a: {2022_value2: 13, 2021_value1: 10, 2022_value1: 15, 2021_value2: 11}
b: {2022_value2: 37, 2021_value1: 20, 2022_value1: 30, 2021_value2: 25}
```

*Note:*

- If performance is concerned, `Collector.of()` would be slightly better because it doesn't create intermediate collections.
- For this approach to work correctly (I mean the code listed above as well as in the question), each combination of `unitId` and `year` should  be unique. Otherwise, consider adding a logic for resolving duplicates.